# Google Docs api for android

Tags: android, google-docs-api

Does anybody know how to share doc on Google Docs from an Android application. Can anybody provide me a full sample code to share a doc on Google Docs?

Answer (score 3):

Please read the manual. Here is the official [Google Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/). Here is the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client) for the previously supported GData API which is now discontinued in favour of newer, JSON based APIs.

Comment: From your second link: "Since GData Java Client Library does not support Android". There you go: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Comment: It does, there is a typo in the documentation.  You can remove your downvote of my answer now.

Comment: Votes are locked after 2 days, sorry. Where exactly do you see a typo there? Please cite.

Comment: The typo is that it does support Android.  It used to not support Android because of a bug in the XML parser, which we've since fixed.